# JavaScript Object/Array newbie (using jQuery)

Tags: jquery, arrays, object

I have a function which needs to return either an array or object. I'm not sure which is best and I'm not sure how to construct it.  Here's what I have so far.  Pay close attention to the comments in ALL CAPS.  The idea is to loop through a set of td cells that contain a 'data-field' attribute, and use the name of the attribute as the variable name and the text contained within the td as the value. The number of properties or values of the array/object are unknown.  Depending on what was clicked to enter into the function, 2-6 values will be needed.

```
function InlineEditMode(rowID, entryType) {
// store current row data in case of cancel
var original = $('#'+rowID).contents();

// DEFINE SOME ARRAY OR OBJECT HERE
// put original values in the newEntry Array with a loop, using the 
// data-field attributes as the name of the array or object variables
// and the text of the td as the value
$('#'+rowID+' td[data-field]').each(function() {
    var field = $(this).attr('data-field');
    var value = $(this).text();

    // BUILD OUT OBJECT OR ARRAY
});
// RETURN ARRAY OR OBJECT
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you need a hashmap/associative array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe something like this would work for your purposes.

```
function InlineEditMode(rowID, entryType) {
// store current row data in case of cancel
var original = $('#'+rowID).contents();

// DEFINE SOME ARRAY OR OBJECT HERE
var buildup = {};

// put original values in the newEntry Array with a loop, using the 
// data-field attributes as the name of the array or object variables
// and the text of the td as the value
$('#'+rowID+' td[data-field]').each(function() {
    var field = $(this).attr('data-field');
    var value = $(this).text();

    // BUILD OUT OBJECT OR ARRAY
    buildup[field] = value;
});
// RETURN ARRAY OR OBJECT

return buildup;
}
```

Comment: why is var buildup defined with the curly brackets {} instead of [].  I thought {} was for objects and [] for arrays.

Comment: Buildup is an object. The notation buildup["foo"] = "Fii" is the same as saying buildup.foo = "Fii".

Comment: I didn't know that.  I much prefer buildup.foo , but i guess I can't use my field and value variables then... is that right?

Comment: Arrays would not be a good container for name-value pairs. Are you wanting to support arrays? How would you expect the name-value pairs to be stored within the array?

Comment: I agree that objects are better. I was just trying to do it like this:
`buildup.field = value`
which wasn't working

Comment: Once the object is built up you can use buildup.foo elsewhere in your code. Feel free to play with this sample I used for testing http://jsfiddle.net/2MDwn/.

Comment: @JoeRobich  Thanks.  That's 2 in one day you've answered for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function InlineEditMode(rowID, entryType) {
// store current row data in case of cancel
var original = $('#'+rowID).contents();

var toReturn = {};

// DEFINE SOME ARRAY OR OBJECT HERE
// put original values in the newEntry Array with a loop, using the 
// data-field attributes as the name of the array or object variables
// and the text of the td as the value
$('#'+rowID+' td[data-field]').each(function() {
    var field = $(this).attr('data-field');
    var value = $(this).text();

    toReturn[field] = value;
});
// RETURN ARRAY OR OBJECT
return toReturn;
}
```